# Getting started with Program Synthesis

Tags: ds.algorithms

There some internet pages:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_synthesis
- http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/sumitg/pubs/synthesis.html
- https://sites.google.com/site/asergrp/bibli/program-synthesis

But, honestly, i can't find entrance to that topic. There are a lot of advanced level talks but only a few "hello world" examples(or completely none).

So where can one start learning about program synthesis ?

Comment: Without knowing what you don't know and what hurdles you have encountered, we cannot help – you already supply many many references (via those links).

Comment: Have you tried learning other current research topics before? This is an active and developing field, so the focus is not "hello world" type examples. James Koppel's answer does have good starting points, but note that they are extremely recent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start with the notes form Ras Bodik's course, Program Synthesis for everyone: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bodik/cs294fa12

The slides from the recent summer school are also useful: https://excape.cis.upenn.edu/summer-school.html